# scala (scanLeft) - how to (functionally) get a Map with cumulated values / frequency

Tags: scala, fold

I am new to Scala and trying to get a Map having cumulative frequencies as values from a Map with the individual ones. So (for an immutable Map persisting the order such as ListMap) value(i) is the sum of all values up to and including i in the original Map as such:

```
val map = ListMap(0.0 -> 0.1, 0.01 -> 0.2, 0.05 -> 0.3, 0.1 -> 0.4)
val resultMap = ListMap(0.0 -> 0.1, 0.01 -> 0.3, 0.05 -> 0.6, 0.1 -> 1.0)
```

Since one would need access to previous key-value pair I came up with an iterative implementation which makes use of mutable.LinkedHashMap and a running total, but I find that messy and **still looking for a way to get a mutable map from the immutable one** (as in line3 below):

```
var cummulativeMap0 = mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[Double, Double]
var total = 0.0
//line3:
val copyMap = mutable.LinkedHashMap(0.0->0.1, 0.01->0.2, 0.05->0.3, 0.1->0.4) 
map.foreach {
      (kv) => { 
          total = total + copyMap.remove(kv._1).get
          cummulativeMap0.put(kv._1 , total) 
          } 
       }
cummulativeMap0
```

Alternatively I was able to use scanLeft but only with the cost of splitting the keys and values in 2 Lists to be zipped later:

```
val cummValues = map.values.scanLeft(0.0){ (a, b)=>a+b }.tail
val cummmulativeMap2 = (map.keys zip cummValues).toMap
```

What is the most idiomatic/functional way to achieve this, is it doable with **scanLeft** directly on the Map? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to zip-unzip it, just ignore the previous key in each step:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

val map = ListMap(0.0 -> 0.1, 0.01 -> 0.2, 0.05 -> 0.3, 0.1 -> 0.4)
val res = map.scanLeft((0.0, 0.0)){
  case ((_, acc), (x, y)) => (x, acc + y)
}

println(res)
```

Gives you:

```
ListMap(0.0 -> 0.1, 0.01 -> 0.3, 0.05 -> 0.6, 0.1 -> 1.0)
```

(up to machine precision, truncated some zeroes from output)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can scanLeft over the elements of the map, using a dummy key in your initial value:

```
val result = map.scanLeft((0.0, 0.0)){case ((_, av),(bk,bv)) => (bk, av + bv)}.tail
```

Comment: missing an '}' before .tail

Comment: Cheers. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with zip+map, mostly because I didn't know about scanLeft. :)

```
scala> val imap = List(0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 1 -> 4)
map: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (1,2), (5,3), (1,4))

// add neutral element to start with for first element
scala> val m = imap.zip ((0,0) :: imap)
m: List[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] = List(((0,1),(0,0)), ((1,2),(0,1)), ((5,3),(1,2)), ((1,4),(5,3)))

// same as in scanLeft:
scala> m.map {case ((a, b), (c, d)) => (a, b + d)}
res153: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (1,3), (5,5), (1,7))
```

(using ints for briefness).